# Find ideals $I,J\subset F[x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n]$ such that $V(I)=V(J)$ but $I\neq J$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, examples-counterexamples, affine-varieties

Find ideals $I,J\subset  F[x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n]$ such that $V(I)=V(J)$ but $I\neq J$

I understand that it is equivalent to show that $V: I\subset F[x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n]\to K^n,\, I\to V(I)$ is not one to one.

I use $I=\lbrace x^3 \rbrace$ and $J=\lbrace x^2\rbrace$ which are distict and $V(I)=V(J)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$
Is my answer right? or I can find better examples, because it looks trivial.

Now which is the secret to find these?

Comment: If you take the ideal $I:=(f(x,y))$ where $f(x,y)\in k[x,y]$ and the ideal $J:=I^2:=(f(x,y)^2)$ it follows $V(I)=V(J)$ but $I \neq I^2$ differ as ideals.

Comment: it is false that $V(I)=V(J) \iff \sqrt{I}=\sqrt{J}$ for example let the field be the real numbers and $I=(1)$ and $J=(x^2+1)$ then $V(I)=V(J)=\emptyset$ but $I\neq J$ which are both equal to their own radicals.

Comment: Thanks I fix the mistake

Comment: But there are a general form of construct this kind of ideals?

Comment: You've written the domain of $V$ as the polynomial ring, but it's actually the set of ideals of that ring, isn't it? Anyway, you have found one very good way to construct this kind of pair of ideals. I don't know whether there is any general form. It's probably easier if you assume the field is algebraically closed.

Comment: Yes, I made a typo, but it is fixed now, I´m gonna try assuming that $K$ is algebraically closed

Comment: putting this as an answer cause the comment was too long. In general if $F$ is not algebraically complete then you have that given any irreducible polynomial $f$ then $V((1))=V((f))=\emptyset$ but you can do more $V(I)=V((f)\cap I)=V(I)\cup V((f))$. You have on the other hand that if the field is algebraically complete then $I(V(I))=\sqrt{I}$ by the Nullstellensatz. So if $V(I)=V(J)\iff \sqrt{I}=\sqrt{J}$ (use the property $ V(I(V(I)))=V(I)$) this gives you a criteria for how to find such $I$ and $J$

Comment: Nota bene: $I(V)$ has nothing to do with the ideal $I$ but it's the ideal of all functions who vanish on $V$

Comment: These is the trick, Thanks I´m gonna work in the idea